# Integration with affine transformation

Tags: integration

**Context**: I am trying to understand whether the $L^{2}$ function space with inner product
$$\langle g_{1}, g_{2}\rangle=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g_{1}(x)g_{2}(x)e^{-x^{\top}x}\,\mathrm dx$$
is closed under the composition with the affine transformation $x\mapsto x+a$ for an arbitrary fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**Question**: More concretely, suppose $g$ is one function in this space satisfying $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g(x)^{2}e^{-x^{\top}x}\,\mathrm dx<\infty$$
We would like to see whether we have
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g(x+a)^{2}e^{-x^{\top}x}\,\mathrm dx<\infty$$

**My approach**: If we perform a change of variables, the above inequality becomes $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g(x)^{2}e^{-(x-a)^{\top}(x-a)}\,\mathrm dx<\infty$$
and thus we just need to show
$$e^{-a^{\top}a}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g(x)^{2}e^{-x^{\top}x}e^{2x^{\top}a}\,\mathrm dx<\infty$$
I am stuck here as I am not sure how to deal with the additional $e^{2x^{\top}a}$ term in the integral.

I would appreciate if anyone can give me some hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample.  In $\mathbb R^1$.
Let $w(x) =e^{-x^2}$.  Our norm is
$$
\|f\|^2 := \int_\mathbb R |f(x)|^2 w(x)\;dx
$$
Consider the function:
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
x^{-1}e^{x^2/2} & x \ge 1
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I claim $f(x)$ is in $L^2$, but $f(x+1)$ is not.  That is,
$$
\int_\mathbb R |f(x)|^2 w(x)\;dx = \int_1^{+\infty} x^{-2} dx = 1 < +\infty
$$
but
$$
\int_\mathbb R |f(x+1)|^2 w(x)\;dx = \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{2x+1}}{(x+1)^2} = +\infty
$$